# Scala-Spark: Convert Dataframe to RDD[Edge]

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, rdd, spark-graphx

I have a dataframe that it represents edges of a graph; this is the schema:

```
root |-- src: string (nullable = true) 
     |-- dst: string (nullable = true) 
     |-- relationship: struct (nullable = false) 
     | |-- business_id: string (nullable = true) 
     | |-- normalized_influence: double (nullable = true)
```

I want to convert it to RDD[Edge] to work with Pregel API and my difficulties is on attribute "relationship". How can convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Edge` is a parameterized class. This means you can store whatever you like in each edge, besides the source and destination ids. In your case, it would probably be an `Edge[Relationship]`. You can use case classes to map both the dataframe and the `RDD[Edge[Relationship]]`:

```
import scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3
case class Relationship(business_id: String, normalized_influence: Double)
case class MyEdge(src: String, dst: String, relationship: Relationship)

val edges: RDD[Edge[Relationship]] = df.as[MyEdge].rdd.map { edge =>
    Edge(
        MurmurHash3.stringHash(edge.src).toLong, // VertexId type is a Long, so we need to hash your string
        MurmurHash3.stringHash(edge.dst).toLong,
        edge.relationship
    )
}
```